# Using two HDMI inputs on one monitor at the same time

Tags: hardware, cpu-architecture, display, hdmi

I want to use my main PC and my secondary PC that I don't use often at the same time but have only one monitor

I don't want to buy a new monitor just for this though, if you have any idea how to render both of the computers to the monitor at the same time please answer

Answer (score 1):

Picture in Picture (showing both inputs at the same time) is a Monitor feature. Unless your monitor's software is capable of doing that, there is no possibility to achieve what you want.

Some newer monitors might have the capabilities of doing what you need, depending on the price range.

Comment: *some* newer monitors.  It's not a widespread feature AFAIK.  I think most budget-priced monitors still only let you swap between inputs.

Comment: Exactly, I saw that feature on the newer wide curved screens, but never on any old monitor I came across until now.

Comment: Not all "new monitors" are high end.  They're still designing and making new budget monitors every year, and those are still non-curved, non-PIP, but with better energy efficiency, and cheaper for the same size, and other features.  Your last sentence is still a serious overstatement.

Comment: That's what I wanted to say, i have edited the answer to reflect what I meant, thanks for hinting it out. I didn't get it the first time.